# Can't connect to my nodejs server on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

So I am testing out Amazon EC2 to see If I can work with this platform. So far I am using the freetier VMI Machine, a small machine runnning Windows Server 2012 with SQL server express.
I have installed NodeJS on it, and I'm running the hello world on it right now.
If I type 127.0.0.1 in my browser on this virtual machine, I can see "Hello World".
Now, I have done the following.

- Open all TCP ports in Amazon Security group for my instance
- Open all ports in the Windows Firewall of this machine.
- Put nodeJS on allowed apps in Windows Firewall.

  - Added an elastic ip for my instance in the Amazon Config Manager.

I still can't do the following :
- ping my server on my elastic ip
- access my server using my static ip address (elastic ip).

So really nothing works and I'm out of options :(
I hope someone can help

Comment: It must be something simple you overlooked.  Are you sure that your instance is running with the security group you modified?

Comment: Yes, and to be sure I had modified all the security groups anyway.
I'll eventually find a solution I guess. I'll update this topic when I do.